# Laravel query builder join after where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I am using laravel 8. I have this mysql command which I want to convert into laravel query builder style:

```
select allocation.*, leav_leave_types.leave_type_code 
from (
    select * from leav_employee_annual_leave_allocations 
    where leave_year_id = $year_id and employee_id = $user_id
) as allocation
left join leav_leave_types on (leav_leave_types.id = allocation.leave_type_id)
```

Actually I want to apply a `where` clause first and then perform a `left join` for better performance.

How can I convert it into query builder style?

Comment: `leav_employee_annual_leave_allocations` would benefit from `INDEX(employee_id, leave_year_id)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing from your query that is not currently in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) is using a subquery as the main table.

This can be done by passing either a `Closure` or a `Builder` instance to the `table()` or `from()` method.

- `DB::table(closure, alias)`
- `DB::table(builder, alias)`
- `DB::query()->from(closure, alias)`
- `DB::query()->from(builder, alias)`

---

Using a Closure:

```php
DB::table(function ($sub) use ($user_id, $year_id) {
        $sub->from('leav_employee_annual_leave_allocations')
            ->where('leave_year', $year_id)
            ->where('employee_id', $user_id);
    }, 'allocation')
    ->select('allocation.*', 'leav_leave_types.leave_type_code')
    ->leftJoin('leav_leave_types', 'leav_leave_types.id', 'allocation.leave_type_id')
    ->get();
```

```php
DB::query()
    ->select('allocation.*', 'leav_leave_types.leave_type_code')
    ->from(function ($sub) use ($user_id, $year_id) {
        $sub->from('leav_employee_annual_leave_allocations')
            ->where('leave_year', $year_id)
            ->where('employee_id', $user_id);
    }, 'allocation')
    ->leftJoin('leav_leave_types', 'leav_leave_types.id', 'allocation.leave_type_id')
    ->get();
```

---

Using a Builder instance

```php
$sub = DB::table('leav_employee_annual_leave_allocations') // or DB::query()->from('leav_employee_annual_leave_allocations')
    ->where('leave_year', $year_id)
    ->where('employee_id', $user_id);

DB::table($sub, 'allocation')
    ->select('allocation.*', 'leav_leave_types.leave_type_code')
    ->leftJoin('leav_leave_types', 'leav_leave_types.id', 'allocation.leave_type_id')
    ->get();
```

```php
// personally my favorite way. I find it very readable.
$sub = DB::table('leav_employee_annual_leave_allocations') // or DB::query()->from('leav_employee_annual_leave_allocations')
    ->where('leave_year', $year_id)
    ->where('employee_id', $user_id);

DB::query()
    ->select('allocation.*', 'leav_leave_types.leave_type_code')
    ->from($sub, 'allocation')
    ->leftJoin('leav_leave_types', 'leav_leave_types.id', 'allocation.leave_type_id')
    ->get();
```

---

The generated SQL looks like this

```sql
select "allocation".*, "leav_leave_types"."leave_type_code" from (
    select * from "leav_employee_annual_leave_allocations"
    where "leave_year" = ? and "employee_id" = ?
) as "allocation"
left join "leav_leave_types" on "leav_leave_types"."id" = "allocation"."leave_type_id"
```

If you want a parenthesis around your join condition to be generated, you should use one of the following notations instead.

```php
leftJoin('leav_leave_types', ['leav_leave_types.id' => 'allocation.leave_type_id'])
```

```
leftJoin('leav_leave_types', function ($join) {
    $join->on(['leav_leave_types.id' => 'allocation.leave_type_id']);
})
```

```
leftJoin('leav_leave_types', function ($join) {
    // will generate a parenthesis if there's more than one condition
    $join->on('leav_leave_types.id', 'allocation.leave_type_id')
         ->on(...) // and condition
         ->orOn(...); // or condition
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could turn the SQL around to

```
select *, 
       ( SELECT leave_type_code
             FROM leav_leave_types
             WHERE id = allocation.leave_type_id
       ) AS leave_type_code
    FROM leav_employee_annual_leave_allocations AS allocation
    where leave_year_id = $year_id and employee_id = $user_id
```

(This might be more efficient.)

In either case `leav_employee_annual_leave_allocations` would benefit from `INDEX(employee_id, leave_year_id)`.